# Problem with php's XSLTProcessor

Tags: php, dita, xslt

I'm trying to use the [XSLTProcessor class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php) in php to generate xhtml from a .dita file based on the [DITA Open Toolkit](http://dita-ot.sourceforge.net/)'s xslt files.

The XSLTProcessor is working with simple xml and xslt files (e.g. with the [samples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT#XSLT_examples) on wikipedia), but it fails with the Open Toolkit's xsls.

The intresting part is that everything works well, if I use xsltproc command from bash on the same computer on the same files (I used no switches).

So, here's my code:

```
<?php
$sXML = file_get_contents('concepts/tools.xml');
# LOAD XML FILE
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->loadXML( $sXML );

# START XSLT
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$XSL = new DOMDocument();

$XSL->load( 'xsl/dita2xhtml.xsl');
$xslt->importStylesheet( $XSL );
#PRINT
print $xslt->transformToXML( $XML );
```

And instead of a valid xhtml file I get an output like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE span PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<span style="background-color: yellow;"><span style="font-weight: bold">[/concept
     {""}) </span>
<span style="background-color: yellow;"><span style="font-weight: bold">[/concept/title
     {""}) </span>Tools<span style="font-weight: bold"> (title]</span></span>
<span style="background-color: yellow;"><span style="font-weight: bold">[/concept/shortdesc
     {""}) </span>Invest in a good set of tools for doing all kinds of tasks around the house.<span style="font-weight: bold"> (shortdesc]</span></span>
<span style="background-color: yellow;"><span style="font-weight: bold">[/concept/conbody
     {""}) </span><span style="background-color: yellow;"><span style="font-weight: bold">[/concept/conbody/p
     {""}) </span>Useful tools include the following items:<span style="font-weight: bold"> (p]</span></span> (...)
```

It's just the first part of the output, but I didn't want copy the whole text here.

Both the xsl file and dita concept file is from the DITA Open Toolkit.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I think you should provide a reduce input sample causing problems or at least a link to the full input in order to test.

Comment: @Alejandro: The dita file is very short, but the xsl file references to a lot of other ones, and they are very big together. Here(http://sourceforge.net/projects/dita-ot/) you can download the DITA Open Toolkit (you don't have to install or run it), wich contains all the files. My test files are: samples/concepts/tools.xml and xsl/dita2xhtml.xsl. I can upload them into a zip file on some server later, if it's better.

Comment: I'm getting the same results with MSXSL. What does the output suppose to be?

Comment: @Alejandro: I don't understand what's going on. I ran the following command: ~/Downloads$ xsltproc DITA-OT1.5.1/xsl/dita2xhtml.xsl DITA-OT1.5.1/samples/concepts/tools.xml -o tools.html (then cat tools.html) and I got the same result, as you, and as above. But if I run ~/Downloads$ xsltproc DITA-OT1.5.1/xsl/dita2xhtml.xsl DITA-OT1.5.1/samples/concepts/tools.xml wich does the same, but dumps the output to the console, I got a well formatted valid xhtml file with title, body, stylesheet reference and everything... Do you think it could be some encoding problem?

Comment: My bad, I used bad parameters. With: ~/Downloads$ xsltproc -o xx.xx DITA-OT1.5.1/xsl/dita2xhtml.xsl DITA-OT1.5.1/samples/concepts/tools.xml && cat xx.xx it's working fine, I've got my valid xhtml doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my issue is solved. The tools.xml had an external dtd reference

```
<!DOCTYPE concept PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Concept//EN"

 "../../dtd/technicalContent/dtd/concept.dtd">
```

wich wasn't loaded by the DOMDocument by default, and that caused all the problems. If you have the same problem, you have to use the [LIBXML_DTDATTR](http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) option like this:

```
$f = 'DITA-OT1.5.1/samples/concepts/tools.xml';
$XML = new DOMDocument();
$XML->load( $f,LIBXML_DTDATTR);
```